# Why Wordpress reveals administrator username under comments list?

Tags: wordpress

Take a closer look in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhBbX.png)! at class that begins with "comment-author-".

On a fresh new Wordpress install, that username is used to login. I don't think it's a good idea to echo that.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an issue. The post author page slug will also be the username.

A common security practise is to have an admin account and an author account. The admin account isn't used to post.

Comment: I know, it's not an issue. The questions is, why? There can be a class like "comment-author-admin" or so... I think we don't need to style individual blog author cooments.